# Adding formatting to rich edit controls using win32 api

Tags: c++, winapi, rtf

I am creating a rich edit text box like so:

```
const char *testText = "Hello \\bworld!";

LoadLibrary("riched20.dll");  

hwndoutbox = CreateWindowEx(
    ES_SUNKEN,
    RICHEDIT_CLASS,
    testText,
        WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        0, 40, 300, 300,
        hwnd, 0, hInstance, NULL);
```

The intended result is to display 'Hello World' with the 'World' in bold.
What am I doing wrong?

*I have a hunch that \b might be an escape code for something, but i cant find much info to back that up*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go and have a look at the specification for [RTF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140301%28v=office.10%29.aspx). For a start, RTF data has a header, and you aren't including that.

In fact, Wikipedia's page on RTF ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)) might have been a good place for you to start. It includes this example text:

```
{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard
This is some {\b bold} text.\par
}
```

... which is a string with a bold word.

The "rich edit control" is a control designed to render RTF.